# He is smart as/for/to be a country person

Tags: prepositions

“He is smart as/for/to be a country person”, which preposition should I use to express the impression that - he’s a countryman but smart?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> He is smart *for* a country person

But it should be noted that this also implies that most country people are *not* smart, and so could be considered a fairly offensive statement.